# Where did they put the Games with Gold menu?

Tags: xbox-one

A link to the list of available Games with Gold used to be on the homepage. Now it's not there. Where did they move the list to?

Comment: Pretty sure its still there?

Comment: @TimmyJim nope. (hence the question)

Comment: I say that because mine is

Comment: Oh. Strange. Not sure what's going on then. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: If you go to the store, is there a link anywhere there for you to use? Otherwise, you should be able to find the current free games with gold by searching the internet and then searching the game in the store in the mean time.

Comment: Nope. Not in store. Yeah I gotta manually search. Sigh. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a button in the store called 'Memberships'.  This button is in the middle, below the second row of icons, third button from the left.  Click there, and you'll be taken to a page which has Games with Gold at the top.

[image: A picture showing where the Memberships button exists]

Edit: Thanks @Evorlor for correcting the name and position.

Comment: "Memberships" button, third from the left, below second row of icons.

Answer (score 0):

My Dashboard still has a square on the right, where the Games With Gold square was, that says something about the "benefits" with Gold. That takes me directly to the Games With Gold screen, which also shows your subscription and buttons to renew it.